# How often should I reach out to a company that has shown interest?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I applied to a company and had two interviews that went well, the only major hurtle is that I was overqualified for the position and they needed to create a set of duties. The person who would be my manager said there is more than enough work, and the discussion is focused on narrowing it down.

I wrote a thank you note after the last interview, then after two weeks sent a email that was not replied to, then shortly after called said manager who said they were actively working on an offer. It has been about two weeks and I would like to reach out but don't want to seem like I am bugging them, what is the best way to proceed? (At this company, have kept actively hunting in the meantime, not going to stop till I sign a contract)

Comment: Fair enough, so it is reasonable to reach out after two weeks just to touch base?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make another call since it has been more than two weeks. I don't think you will be bugging them as it shows your interest to work for the company. You always look for other jobs when waiting for this one.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, I would make it more personal and invite btheb hiring manager to lunch if possible.

It is true that some companies take longer then others to write an offer letter, especialy since it sound like they are creating a new position for you, but the best way I found to get to the bottom of what is going on is to talk with the hiring manager face and what better way to do it then over lunch.

Lunch is a low stress environment for all parties and it allows you to impress in a neutral setting. Plus everybody has to eat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I managed groups for some 20 years and during this time i employed this strategy sucessfully as well as I had it used on me.

Comment: Didn't want to post it yet as I wasn't finished. I always liked potetial candidates that used the strategy… matter of fact I kept in contact with some for years even though they did not end up working for me for various reasons.